# How to use mobx's type definitions with the UMD distribution?

Tags: typescript, mobx

My project is still at a stage where I don't use a bundler or browserify but rather reference all third-party Javascript files individually in a version suited for that.

For mobx, that would be the UMD version, which can be used in the browser directly.

I don't know how to get `mobx.d.ts` to work. I use the one from npm, as I found no other.

The definition file appears to be different from the ones I had before, to be used with import statements: Simply triple-slash-referencing the file does nothing.

However, I don't want to use import statements at this point as that would force me to use a module system for my own Javascript.

So can I use the mobx type definition file another way?